# Does basic Windows 8.1 support multiple active local user sessions, or do I need Windows 8.1 PRO?

Tags: windows-8, session

Two family members use the same computer locally. Can both have active sessions on a Windows 8.1 basic edition, or does one person need to log off before the other can log on?

(Windows 8.1 PRO supports this, but I'm interested in the basic edition)

Comment: Windows does't support that on any non-server edition.  The machine is licensed for one person at a time.

Comment: Wrong. I have two local users signed in on a Windows 8.1 Pro computer right now. When you switch user, the other remains signed in, and you can switch back. I don't need the to users to be able to manipulate things at the same time (ie. one of them via remote desktop) - I just want to be able to switch users without logging off.

Comment: @Andrew, why are you saying Zoredache is wrong? He/she clearly states his/her post doesn't support this functionality due to the license!!! He never said it was not possible.

Comment: There is one keyboard, only one person at a time can use it locally. If the license had forbidden even that, they would have denied quick user switching, like they did in the Windows 7 Starter Edition, as mentioned below.

Answer (score 1):

All windows editions since XP have allowed multiple users to be logged in at once.

Comment: As I can recall, Windows 7 Home version forced you to log off before you could switch users, and Professional version didn't. That's why I would like someone to verify this with the Win8.1 basic version.

Comment: I've used windows 7 home premium and it's allowed fast switching, I can't imagine professional didn't have it. Fast switching can be disable was it installed at work or a public place? I have windows 8.1, the basic version is just called that, and I have had three accounts logged in at once.

Comment: Thank you, that's helpful, you could add it as an answer :)

Comment: Just some more info - I think it was Windows 7 Starter (and not Windows 7 Home) which didn't allow fast user switching - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7_editions